# Where can I find a basic implementation of the EM clustering algorithm for R?

Tags: r, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a basic implementation of EM clustering in R. So far, [what I can find](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) seem to be specialized or 'some-assembly-required' versions of it. For example, the implementation from `mclust` defines a range of parameters that I'm not familiar with and doesn't take a parameter for *k*. What I am looking for is something closer to the kmeans implementation that comes with R, or [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/)'s [implementation of EM](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/EM.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reading the documentation for `mclust`?

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/mclust.pdf

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Expectation_Maximization_%28EM%29

Make sure to choose the desired model (probably `VVV`?), and if you want a fixed `k`, then set `G` to a single value instead of the default `1:9`.

Try this:

```
library(mclust)
m <- Mclust(data, 4:4, c("VVV"), control=emControl(tol=e1-4))
```

I must say I don't use or like R much. It has tons of stuff, but it doesn't fit together. It's just random stuff written independently by random people and then uploaded to a central repository. But there is no QA at all, and nobody that makes libraries compatible.

Comment: I had looked at those before, but didn't really understand them. I'm brand new to R. The documentation says the function `em` only takes an `mclustModelName` as an input, and not an `mclustModel` where `G` is contained. So how would I set `G`? Also, from a statistics standpoint, I don't know what to do with the members of `parameters` (eg. `pro` `mean` etc.). Finally, the function returns a matrix of probabilities rather than a vector of cluster memberships, so I if I wanted the latter, I would have to implement the final step myself?

Comment: I don't use `R` either. But I remember that it took me like 5 minutes to figure it out. The problem with R is that every package is different, they do not fit together. And in my experiments, it was slower than the other choices such as ELKI (actually R ran out of memory IIRC).

Comment: You don't use R, but have an opinion on it. I agree that it could be that some packages do not fit together, but I think this is typical for all opensource software that is not explicitely designed to work together. In some areas, packages are homogenized. But this is a community initiatve. Is the situation much better in Python or Java?  Matlab I can imagine has more cohesion, but that costs 10k or more.

Comment: @Anony Thanks for the help. It looks like this might do the trick.